# How to get non-bound WPF combobox to show the selecteditem instead of {System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem:

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

This has probably been answered somewhere, but I'm not sure how to phrase the question.

Is there a XAML only way to create a NON-BOUND WPF ComboBox that shows the actual SelectedItem (or SelectedValue) instead of "{System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: item 1}"?
Right now, the selectedItem (or SelectedValue) requires splitting the string at the colon, then removing the last curly brace from the string.

Is there a way to do this without explicit code?

```
                <ComboBox x:Name="cboTilePattern" Height="22" Width="200" Margin="0,0,20,0" >
                <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">Square: Quarter Turn</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Square: Monolithic Horizontal</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Square: Monolithic Vertical</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Rectangle: Chevron</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Rectangle: Brick Horizontal</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Rectangle: Brick Horizontal Flip</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Rectangle: Brick Vertical</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Rectangle: Brick Vertical Flip</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Rectangle: Monolithic Horizontal</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>Rectangle: Monolithic Vertical</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>2 Squares: Checkerboard</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>2 Squares: Quarterturn Checkerboard</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One nifty technique is to set the `SelectedValuePath` to either `Content` or `Tag`.  Eg:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="combo" SelectedValuePath="Content">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="item 1" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="item 2" />
    </ComboBox>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=combo,Path=SelectedValue}" />
</StackPanel>
```